# Make Ansible use the right IP

Tags: macos, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

i'm currently having an odd problem with Ansible

I used to change pretty often the IP address of my hosts in my hosts file. Didn't have any problem so far. But now, even though i changed the IP address in my hosts file, Ansible is still using a previous IP.

Here is the content of my hosts file :

```
[test-host]
test ansible_host=172.16.0.10 ansible_port=22 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/test/virtualbox/private_key
```

I even specified the hosts file to use when i'm running my playbook :

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts.file
```

I already tried to reinstall Ansible, delete the tmp folder.

I saw that if i'm typing `ansible-inventory -list` i can see the old IP

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "test": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.0.10", 
                "ansible_port": 22, 
                "ansible_private_key_file": ".vagrant/machines/test/virtualbox/private_key", 
                "ansible_user": "vagrant"
            }
        }
    },
```

How can i force Ansible to use the hosts.file instead of this "cache" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command with `-vvv`

```
ansible-inventory -vvv --list
```

At the beginning of the output find all `Parsed ... inventory source`. Review the sources to find out where does the problematic host come from.

Comment: Thanks ! My hosts file wasn't parsed properly by Ansible because of a "-". I've executed the playbook without any "-". Then i tried again with all the "-" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like ansible is using his own cache :
[Caching Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html?highlight=caching#caching-facts)

try running your playbook with option `--flush-cache`, maybe that will solve the issue

Comment: i'm curious: if you change the name of your host to test2, will it change name+@IP in ansible-inventory output ?

Comment: I changed the name in the hosts file, of course now it is working because it picked up the new name but the output of `ansible-inventory --list` remains the same so if i rename the host 'test' again, it will not work

Comment: even with `ansible-inventory -i hosts.file` ?